# Frustum culling decreases framerate in debug but improves it in release

Tags: sfml, visual-studio-debugging, bounding-box, frustum, culling

I'm making a tilebased game in SFML and decided to implement a simple bounding-box frustum culling to only draw the tiles that are in the viewport of the camera. The result was a success, as it tripled my framerate! However, there was a cache. When running the game in debug the framerate is instead lowered by the implemented frustum culling. It went from 90 to 30 fps in debug, while in release it went from 100 to about 350 fps.

The culling simply checks for each tiles rectangle, whether it intersects with the rectangle of the viewport. If it does, it is drawn. The game renders several views for splitscreen and the code looks like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    {
```

....

```
// Calculate viewport rectangle.
        IntRect viewRect;
        viewRect.width = views[i]->getSize().x;
        viewRect.height = views[i]->getSize().y;
        viewRect.left = views[i]->getCenter().x - views[i]->getSize().x / 2;
        viewRect.top = views[i]->getCenter().y - views[i]->getSize().y / 2;

        // Loop throug level tiles and render them.
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < tileLayers.size(); j++)
        {
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < tileLayers[j].size(); k++)
            {
                if (tileLayers[j][k]->collide(viewRect))
                    tileLayers[j][k]->drawSprite(window);
            }
        }
```

....

```
bool StaticGameObject::collide(IntRect rectangle)
{
    // Private member variable collisionRect.
    // Width and height is set in constructor.
    collisionRect.left = getPosition().x;
    collisionRect.top = getPosition().y;

    if (collisionRect.intersects(rectangle))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I remove the intersect calls for the rectangle, the framerate goes back up to 90 fps. I'm very confused to as why this is happening.

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with compiler optimization? Chances are your code is not optimized in debug mode - which is good - but is in release. Try temporarily turning on optimization in your debug build to see if that accounts for the fps difference.

Comment: Also: welcome to SO! If you have any questions about how our community operates, chances are they have an answer in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Thanks! I'm somewhat new to c++ and visual studio. How do you change compiler optimization?

Comment: In VS you can access the option in the "Solution Explorer". Right-click your project (not the solution) and choose "properties". A new tab should appear with all your project properties. Make sure you are in the "Build" settings on the new tab. Since you want to look at debug settings, choose debug from the "Configuration" drop-down. Check "Optimize Code", save, and rebuild.

Comment: Remember to turn that off after you've determined whether it's the cause. Optimized code is not guaranteed to execute in the same way you wrote it even though you'll get the same result (except faster/smaller). It makes debugging nearly impossible ;)

Comment: I've looked everywhere but there is no "Build" tab in properties. There's "C/C++", "Linker" etc, but no "Build" tab.

Comment: Hmm... must be misremembering. I'm away from my PC right now, but I'll take a look around when I get home. What license/version of VS are you using?

Comment: Visual studio professional 2013, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry - I was thinking about the properties for C# projects. For C++ projects the optimization settings can be found under "Configuration Properties" > "C/C++" > "Optimization". You can flip between Release and Debug to check out the differences - make sure to record your changes so you can reverse them.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to change the optimization settings but at first it wasn't working. It conflicted with two other settings. These were "Debug information format" and "Basic runtime checks". When I changed these settings alone, without changing optimization, the framerate was increased to 150 fps, making the culling improve the debug fps also. I still have no idea why this works though and if I should keep it this way.

Comment: When you compile a release build it is assumed all your debugging is done. This means that you don't need a way to attach a debugger to your program while it runs. It also means that the compiler can alter the way the program executes to make it more efficient - a process known as optimization. As a simple example say you code the lines `int x = 5 * 4 + 6; x += 4;`. When debugging each line executes separately, but in optimized code your compiler probably realizes that it can just do `int x = 30;`.

Comment: Because your code is much more efficient with those options changed, we know that the efficiency is the result of optimizations like the above. The compiler has found a way to turn your code into a more efficient, but equivalent, version of itself. Unfortunately the efficient code doesn't match what your looking at any more, which is why it isn't useful for debugging. Consider: in the example above when the optimized code executes `int x = 30;`, which line of the original code is it on?

Comment: So no - for your sanity you should not keep this on during debugging. Now that you know what's going on, though, hopefully the lower FPS while debugging will weigh on you a little less. Remember: everyone *else* that plays your game will be working on a release/high FPS copy!

Comment: I see but I still don't really understand how the code that massively improves the release framerate can decrease the debug framerate. Is the SFML intersect functions just not optimised for debugging?

Comment: From the tests you ran it would seem that without optimization the overhead of calculating the intersections outweighs the benefits of drawing fewer objects, which results in decreased framerate in your debug build. When optimized, however, the code that calculates the intersections becomes more efficient, which leads to increased framerate in release (or debug when the code is optimized).

Comment: If you got SFML through regular channels (probably the case unless you built the libs yourself), I can assure you that it is optimized. Hard to say why this is happening without further testing. Since you've isolated the problem my guess would be it's not the cost of `Rect<T>::intersect`'s execution that's causing the overhead, but the [function call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) itself.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a ton! I suppose the overall point is that I should keep it this way because it will greatly improve the published product. Thanks again, Conduit!

Comment: No trouble, happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synopsis of the lengthy discussion in the comments:

Use of the frustum culling algorithm resulted in significant overhead, which had the effect of decreasing the overall framerate in a debug build. In a release build the compiler optimized away the extra overhead resulting in a framerate increase. Unfortunately this is a necessary evil, as optimized code makes debugging impossible.